# How to copy a folder by another, but NOT by merging/adding

Tags: directory, file-copy

I am doing backups of a directory with a simple:

```
cp -R /production/directory /backups/location
```

Sometimes I need to restore a backup, but doing:

```
cp -R /backups/location/* /production/directory
```

or

```
cp -RT /backups/location /production/directory
```

has the unwanted (in my case) effect, of keeping files present in `/production/directory`
 but not in the backup, while I want them removed, to get things in the exact same state as when the backup was done.

Is there any magic switch, or other simple command, to perform that, or do I need to manually remove the whole directory first ?

Comment: You could use `rsync` as follow  `rsync -r --delete-during /backup/location /production/directory` which will scan directories while syncing and put the same content of `/backup/location/` to `/production/directory`

Comment: This will create an _additional_ directory (`location` with your command, or `directory` if I add that to source), _inside_ the /production/directory.

Comment: so include the trailing slash. Use the following:  `rsync -r --delete-during /backup/location/ /production/directory`

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I was searching for an option and missed the trailing slash trick in the manual. Can you turn it into an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rsync` to achieve what you want.

```
rsync -r --delete-during /backup/location/ /production/directory
```

For more on see `man rsync`

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a command called `rm -R` that removes a whole directory.
So you start your restore with `rm -R /production/directory`, followed by the restore command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I mentioned manual remove in my question though, as a last resort. I was searching for something more elegant (I think rsync is probably faster too).